# Responsive web design css media queries and Iphone different resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using media queries on my app and it seems to work well and show up well in http://www.responsinator.com/ but when I view in a real iPhone 4 my webpage is not readable at all. It looks all zoomed in.

Trying to find out the actual cause, it seems that responsinator shows iPhone 4 resolution as 320 x 480 whereas this website http://www.iphoneresolution.com/ shows as 640×960. My iPhone looks to be at 640×960. How should I handle these cases in CSS media queries?

Comment: @kleinfreund: I don't have anything like this. Should I add that?

Comment: The iPhone has a screen resolution of 320x480 at 163 ppi as does the iPhone 2 and 3. The iPhone 4 has 640 × 960 at 326 ppi, and the iPhone 5, 1,136 × 640 at 326 ppi.

Comment: @Jack Yes, try it out please.

Comment: Just so you know, whilst the iphone 4 resolution is 640 x 960, the default for websites on the iphone is 320 x 480

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the viewport meta tag to the `head`-area of your html files:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

This code makes your website scale properly.